# How do I run a QuantumCircuit?

Tags: python, quantum-computing, qiskit

I'm fairly new to quantum algorithms and I went from IBMQ Composer to the Python style of writing circuits. My question is: The code bellow just draws the circuit, is there a way to run the circuit and get the output without having to write a separate programs for visualization and execution? I looked into the "QuantumCircuit" functions (from the qiskit library), but none seem to do what I want.

```py
# importing Qiskit
from qiskit import IBMQ, Aer
from qiskit.providers.ibmq import least_busy
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, transpile, assemble

# import basic plot tools
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
# from qiskit_textbook.tools import simon_oracle

deutsch_circuit = QuantumCircuit(2, 1)

deutsch_circuit.h(0)    
deutsch_circuit.x(1)
deutsch_circuit.h(1)
deutsch_circuit.cx(0, 1)

deutsch_circuit.h(0)

deutsch_circuit.measure(0, 0)
deutsch_circuit.draw()
```

Comment: https://qiskit.org/documentation/intro_tutorial1.html

Comment: @YaelBen-Haim Thank you. I have no idea how I missed that